# Razor C# SqlDataClient Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

(Using Visual Studio 2015 / ASP.net with C#)

I'm getting an error that says:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Datal.dll but was not handled in user code.
>   Additional information: Incorrect syntax near ')'

The SQL statement I have tested and it works just fine, I've checked every parenthesis and can't seem to figure out what is wrong here?

Can someone help?

The code is here (I pointed out the line that VS flagged)

```
 <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>First</th>
                <th>Last</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Permission</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
  <tbody>
            @{
                string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnString"].ConnectionString;
                var sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_users ORDER BY Id ASC)";
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();  //*** This is the line that VS flags **

                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>@reader["Id"].ToString()</td>
                                <td>@reader["FNAME"].ToString()</td>
                                <td>@reader["LNAME"].ToString()</td>
                                <td>@reader["USERNAME"].ToString()</td>
                                <td>@reader["EMAIL"].ToString()</td>
                                <td>@reader["PERMISSION"].ToString()</td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                        if (!reader.IsClosed)
                        {
                            reader.Close();
                        }
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        </tbody>
     </table>
```

Comment: I bet if used a `try...catch` you could find out what the error really is.

Comment: Yeah...this is pretty pathetic...I probably just need to go to bed. I voted to close this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the ")" from the SQL statement

Answer (score 5):

Replace:

**From:**

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_users ORDER BY Id ASC)";
```

**To:**

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_users ORDER BY Id ASC";
```